# Problem with network interfaces in Wireshark

Tags: network-manager, vmware, wireshark

I have the latest version of Ubuntu on VMware virtual machine. I have to capture layer 2 (802.1 Q) packets in Wireshark, but the problem is that when I start Ubuntu I cannot capture these types of packets until I restart the network interfaces with `nmcli n off` then `nmcli n on` commands. Is there a solution for this?, I would like to not have to always restart the interfaces when using Wireshark.

Comment: Please be specific with details; that *latest* release of Ubuntu is Ubuntu 23.04 (2023-April release), so please just use it, as many people on sites like this refer to earlier releases such as Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as the *latest* despite it being 3 releases ago as they didn't mention the LTS qualifier.  How did you start `wireshark`, was it with elevated permissions?